# What made it an opportune time to roll out the Russian Flu Vaccine?

Tags: plot-explanation, utopia

There is some heavy spoiler content for anyone who hasn't seen at least the 1st series of [Utopia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utopia_(UK_TV_series))

So, towards the finale of season 1 we finally learn that the Russian Flu Vaccine is actually...

> ... a smokescreen as a way of deploying Janus, the population sterilizing drug that The Network hopes to use to bring about population control.

As we find out in the last episode, the key to the success of this operation lies within...

> .. Jessica Hyde's blood, as her father injected the only working Janus formula into her before she was rescued from the facility.

It was my understanding from both the events of Season 1 and the prologue to Season 2 that this is the reason she is being pursued by The Network.

However, long before she surfaces, the Network is deploying a very specific series of events in order to manipulate public interest in the vaccine, and to use the wave of public sentiment to have it rolled out globally within a short period of time.

What stimulated the Network to begin this strategy at *that* specific moment? When we consider that...

> they had not yet captured Jessica Hyde, who was the key to the formula...

What possible motivation would they have for executing a plan of which they were, at the time of release, unable to complete? Was there a specific reason that made it pertinent for The Network to step up its game at that moment?